how to add item into a list in another state, when call api success flutter bloc
My idea is the first time I add load a list from api and I get GateInLoaded state with some list in it,
Then I can call api Add to add a new item in that list, if the response has no error
here is 3 files of my bloc
gate_in_state.dart
part of 'gate_in_bloc.dart';


class GateInState extends Equatable {
  const GateInState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class GateInInitial extends GateInState {}

final class GateInLoading extends GateInState {}

final class GateInLoaded extends GateInState {
  final List<contGateInModel> listGateIn;
  final List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel> listHangTau;
  final List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel> listHTNhap;

  final List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel> listKichCo;
  final List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel> listPhanloaivo;
  final List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel> listPhanLoaiHong;
  GateInLoaded({
    required this.listGateIn,
    required this.listHangTau,
    required this.listHTNhap,
    required this.listKichCo,
    required this.listPhanloaivo,
    required this.listPhanLoaiHong,
  });

  GateInLoaded copyWith({
    List<contGateInModel>? listGateIn,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listHangTau,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listHTNhap,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listKichCo,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listPhanloaivo,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listPhanLoaiHong,
  }) {
    return GateInLoaded(
      listGateIn: listGateIn ?? this.listGateIn,
      listHangTau: listHangTau ?? this.listHangTau,
      listHTNhap: listHTNhap ?? this.listHTNhap,
      listKichCo: listKichCo ?? this.listKichCo,
      listPhanloaivo: listPhanloaivo ?? this.listPhanloaivo,
      listPhanLoaiHong: listPhanLoaiHong ?? this.listPhanLoaiHong,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        listGateIn,
        listHangTau,
        listHTNhap,
        listKichCo,
        listPhanloaivo,
        listPhanLoaiHong
      ];
}

final class EditGateInState extends GateInState {}

final class GateInLoadError extends EditGateInState {
  final String error;

  GateInLoadError({required this.error});
}

final class AddGateInError extends EditGateInState {
  final String error;

  AddGateInError({
    required this.error,
  });
}

final class AddGateInSuccess extends EditGateInState {
  final String idCont;

  AddGateInSuccess({required this.idCont});
}

final class UpdateGateInError extends EditGateInState {
  final String error;

  UpdateGateInError({required this.error});
}

final class UpdateGateInSuccess extends EditGateInState {
  final String idCont;

  UpdateGateInSuccess({required this.idCont});
}


gate_in_event.dart
part of 'gate_in_bloc.dart';

sealed class GateInEvent extends Equatable {
  const GateInEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class FetchInitEvent extends GateInEvent {}

class AddNewGateIn extends GateInEvent {
  final contGateInModel item;

  const AddNewGateIn({required this.item});
}

class UpdateGateIn extends GateInEvent {
  final int index;
  final contGateInModel item;

  const UpdateGateIn({required this.index, required this.item});
}


gate_in_bloc.dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:container_repair_tancang/func/gatein/get_list_gatein.dart';
import 'package:container_repair_tancang/func/gatein/insert_edit_gatein.dart';
import 'package:container_repair_tancang/models/gatein/item_cont.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../../../../common/common_varriable.dart';
import '../../../../func/danhmuc/get_dmuc.dart';
import '../../../../models/danhmuc_doituong.dart';

part 'gate_in_event.dart';
part 'gate_in_state.dart';

class GateInBloc extends Bloc<GateInEvent, GateInState> {
  GateInBloc() : super(const GateInState()) {
    on<FetchInitEvent>(fetchInitEvent);
    on<AddNewGateIn>(addNewGateIn);
  }

  FutureOr<void> fetchInitEvent(
      FetchInitEvent event, Emitter<GateInState> emit) async {
    emit(GateInLoading());
    final response = await getListGateIn(listGateInRequest(
        TuNgay: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.now()),
        DenNgay: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(DateTime.now()),
        IDDanhMucHangTau: '',
        SoContainer: ''));

    if (response.ErrorMsg != '') {
      emit(GateInLoadError(error: response.ErrorMsg));
    } else {
      final listKichCo = await getDmuc(IDDanhMucLoaiDoiTuongKichCoContainer);
      final listHTNhap = await getDmuc(IDDanhMucLoaiDoiTuongHinhThucNhap);
      final listHangTau = await getDmuc(IDDanhMucLoaiDoiTuongHangTau);
      final listPlHong = await getDmuc(IDDanhMucLoaiDoiTuongMaPhanLoaiHong);
      final listPlVo = await getDmuc(IDDanhMucLoaiDoiTuongMaPhanLoaiVo);
      // check xem lấy dmuc có lỗi không
      var tempErr = findEmptyList(
          listKichCo, listHTNhap, listHangTau, listPlHong, listPlVo);
      if (tempErr != null) {
        emit(GateInLoadError(error: 'Lỗi khi tải $tempErr'));
        return;
      }
      Iterable iList = jsonDecode(response.Data);

      var listGateIn = List<contGateInModel>.from(
          iList.map((e) => contGateInModel.fromMap(e)));
      log(listGateIn.length.toString());

      emit(GateInLoaded(
        listGateIn: listGateIn,
        listHTNhap: listHTNhap,
        listHangTau: listHangTau,
        listKichCo: listKichCo,
        listPhanLoaiHong: listPlHong,
        listPhanloaivo: listPlVo,
      ));
    }
  }
}

Future<List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>> getDmuc(String id) async {
  var response = await getDMucDoiTuong(
      DanhMucDoiTuongListRequest(idDanhMucLoaiDoiTuong: id));
  Iterable iList = jsonDecode(response.Data);
  var result = List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>.from(
      iList.map((e) => DanhMucDoiTuongModel.fromJson(e)));
  return result;
}

String? findEmptyList(
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listKichCo,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listHTNhap,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listHangTau,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listPlHong,
    List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel>? listPlVo) {
  if (listKichCo == null || listKichCo.isEmpty) return 'listKichCo';
  if (listHTNhap == null || listHTNhap.isEmpty) return 'listHTNhap';
  if (listHangTau == null || listHangTau.isEmpty) return 'listHangTau';
  if (listPlHong == null || listPlHong.isEmpty) return 'listPlHong';
  if (listPlVo == null || listPlVo.isEmpty) return 'listPlVo';
  return null; // All lists are not empty
}

FutureOr<void> addNewGateIn(
    AddNewGateIn event, Emitter<GateInState> emit) async {
      
  var response = await insertGateIn(event.item).then((value) {
    if (value.ErrorMsg == '') {
      var temp = contGateInModel.fromMap(jsonDecode(value.Data));
      // here I want to add it in to the listGateIn  of GateInLoaded state before
      // I think somthing like state.copyWith bt don't know how
    } else {
      // show add error state
    }
  });


 
}


ui screen
class ListGateInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListGateInScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListGateInScreen> createState() => _ListGateInScreenState();
}

class _ListGateInScreenState extends State<ListGateInScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<GateInBloc>().add(FetchInitEvent());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('List GateIn'),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            var bloc = context.read<GateInBloc>();

            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(MyPath.editGateIn,
                arguments: {'isUpdate': false, 'gateInBloc': bloc});
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        body: BlocConsumer<GateInBloc, GateInState>(
          listener: (pre, next) {
            if (next is AddGateInSuccess) {
              // ? do somthing here ?
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is GateInLoading) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else if (state is GateInLoaded) {
              if (state.listGateIn.isEmpty) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text('Hôm nay chưa có dữ liệu'),
                );
              } else {
                return BlocProvider(
                  create: (context) => EditGateinBloc(),
                  child: MyListView(state: state),
                );
              }
            } else if (state is GateInLoadError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(state.error),
              );
            }
            return const SizedBox();
          },
        ));
  }
}

Already search but I can't find solution, I can't use final state = this.state or some thing else like state.copyWith
So should I find solution in bloc file or in ui file ?
Like add func in listner of consumerBLoc when the state is AddGateInSuccess?

You can try this code with the comments I describe below
Future addNewGateIn(
  AddNewGateIn event,
  Emitter<GateInState> emit,
) async {
  var response = await insertGateIn(event.item).then((value) {
    if (value.ErrorMsg == '') {
      // I assume you want to add temp item here to current list
      var temp = contGateInModel.fromMap(jsonDecode(value.Data));

      //To be sure current state is GateInLoaded, not other state loading, initial, ...
      if (state is GateInLoaded) {
        final currentState = state as GateInLoaded;
        // You need to clone newList by [... ], this is important because it creates newList with new address, otherwise
        // Bloc will not recognize that your list has changed.
        final newList = [...currentState.listGateIn];
        newList.add(temp);
        emit(currentState.copyWith(
          listGateIn: newList,
        ));
      }
    } else {
      // show add error state
    }
  });
}


oh so every time i want to edit it i allways have to check the state is GateInLoaded right. Thanks for your answer. But when I use your code. It do not recognize 'state' here

Move your addNewGateIn inside GateInBloc class, you are putting it outside

oh I see, due to created it below another func so I don't recognize that. thanks

Can you take a look back at gate_in_state, Is there somthing wrong with it, because even in this part , it still don't know listGateIn of current state ? code  if (state is GateInLoaded) {  ... }

sorry I forgot, you need to cast it, check my edited answer

oh , so I need to cast the state.copyWith below too right ?thanks

Yes right, let use a local variable to cast it like I did in my edited answer

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
